# Update a pandas dataframe with an array of value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and a array.
I would like to update this array to dataframe.

For example:

**Input**
*DataFrame*

```
Time | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
prod1| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
prod2| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
prod3| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
```

*Array*
productList = [3,4,5]

**Output**

```
Time | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
prod1| 0 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
prod2| 0 | 0 | 4 | 4 | 4 |
prod3| 0 | 0 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
```

And this is my effort.

```
Product_matrix = pd.DataFrame(index=['Prod1','Prod2','Prod3','Prod4','Prod5'], columns=[x for x in range(1,30)])
Product_matrix[:] = 0

import numpy
a=Product_matrix
b=numpy.transpose([6,5,7,0,0])
a.iloc[:,3:6]=[x + b for x in a.iloc[:,3:6]]
a
```

Answer (score 0):

create an index for the DataFrame with the product names. We can then assign the values in the array to the corresponding time columns for each product using the iloc method. We can specify the rows with ':' to select all rows, and specify the columns with the range of time values to update.

Try this

```py
import pandas as pd

# Input DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    '1': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    '2': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    '3': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    '4': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    '5': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'prod1': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'prod2': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'prod3': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
})

# Array with updated values
productList = [3, 4, 5]

# Update DataFrame
for i, prod in enumerate(df.index):
    df.iloc[i, 3:6] = productList

print(df)
```